# Batch to Create a Subdirectory for Each file in Main Directory

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a batch file that loops through a folder, inserting a line of text into each CSV in a folder and generating a file that counts the lines of each file.
I want to also generate a subdirectory in the main folder for each CSV file, without including the ".csv" extension. The code below seems like it should work, (it works when I isolate the three lines to their own bat file!) but in the loop, it returns the same value for the folder name each iteration of the loop. How do I make the dirname variable update with the current value?

```
copy NUL count.txt
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" %%f | find /C ":""

        for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
        echo %%f   !number!>>count.txt

        SET filename=%%f
        SET dirname=%filename:~0,13%
        mkdir %dirname%

    type header.txt >%%f.new
    type %%f >>%%f.new
    move /y %%f.new %%f
 )
```

Comment: `SET dirname=!filename:~0,13!` should do the trick. You need to use delayed expansion just like you did for number.

Comment: Y'all wanna make the Answer and mark this as solved?

Comment: @13ruce Great! Answer written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In the loop, it returns the same value for the folder name each iteration of the loop

```
SET dirname=%filename:~0,13%
```

You need to use delayed expansion just like you did for number:

```
SET dirname=!filename:~0,13!
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.